# How to add custom User object to Spring Security Context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am getting "Cannot initiate; default constructor not found" error. when i try to put my own User object in Spring Security Context.

Below is sample code.

```
class CurrentUser extends User{
     private Long user_id;
     private String user_otherDetails;
     CurrentUser(...,user_id,user_otherDetails){
         super(...);
         this.user_id = user_id;
         this.user_otherDetails = user_otherDetails;
     }
}
```

And if add the default constructor then i am getting compilation error as "Default constructor is not available in parent class".

Can someone provide an example to add custom user object which either extends Spring securitys' User class or implements UserDeails interface.

Comment: can you show us your User class ?

Comment: I exactly replicated my CurrentUser class apart from adding few more overridden constructors one with 3 params and other with 8/9 params

Comment: that is the problem .. when you are doing the `super(...)` so where is this constructor in the User class ?

Comment: User class will have two constructors. The first one is which accepts three parameters username,password,authorities. The second one is which accepts more parameters along with those 3 params like isAccountNonExpired, isPasswordNonExpired and other few. Springs User class will not have default constructor or it is private. Due to this reason, it gives error could not found default constructor.